# How to dynamically add a table row with textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table where each row contains 4 cells and each cell contains a textbox
by default. I have only 1 row and a button that allows me to add an additional row every time it's clicked.

How do I dynamically add table rows containing textboxes in Javascript?

I would also like to have their textbox id change:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox1" />
<input type="text" id="txtbox2" />
```

Right now, I have code that adds the cells:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertRow(){
                var table=document.getElementById("tbSibling");
                var row=table.insertRow(2);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    }
</script>
```

**The Table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Occupation and Employer</th>
        <th>Add</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtAge" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtGender" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtOccupation" /></td>
            <td id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onclick="insertRow();">add</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @fragilewindows When editing a post: Please remove salutations/closings that don't pertain to the question. See [this post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, wasn't sure whether to remove from questions. I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check with this, it's all you want, by using pure javascript.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/leftstick/DVEXG/)

```
var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
            var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("input");
                t1.id = "txtName"+index;
                cell1.appendChild(t1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("input");
                t2.id = "txtAge"+index;
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var t3=document.createElement("input");
                t3.id = "txtGender"+index;
                cell3.appendChild(t3);
            var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
            var t4=document.createElement("input");
                t4.id = "txtOccupation"+index;
                cell4.appendChild(t4);
      index++;

}
```

Comment: No IDs for inputs. Questioner wants different IDs for all dynamically generated inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/n2AfC/2/)**

```
    var ctr = 1;
$('#myTable').on('click', '.button-add', function () {
    ctr++;
    var txtName = "txtName" + ctr;
    var txtAge = "txtAge" + ctr;
    var txtGender = "txtGender" + ctr;
    var txtOccupation = "txtOccupation" + ctr;
    var newTr = '<tr><td><input type="text" id=' + txtName + ' /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + txtAge + ' /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + txtGender + ' /></td><td><input type="text" id=' + txtOccupation + ' /></td><td id="btnAdd" class="button-add">Add</td></tr>';
    $('#myTable').append(newTr);
});
```

Comment: All textboxes in different rows have same IDs @Vond

Answer (score 3):

just create a html code with a textbox code on it then append it on the element

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){
   $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>row</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>");
});
```

a working code for you http://jsfiddle.net/WNDQJ/1/

Comment: I'm not a fan of condensing everything to one long line, but this definitely worked really well for what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function(e) {
    $('#myTable tr:last').after(
        '<tr><td><input type="text" id="txtName' + $("tr:last")[0].rowIndex + '" /></td><td><input type="text" id="txtAge' + $("tr:last")[0].rowIndex + '" /></td><td><input type="text" id="txtGender' + $("tr:last")[0].rowIndex + '" /></td><td><input type="text" id="txtOccupation' + $("tr:last")[0].rowIndex + '" /></td></tr>'
    );
});
```

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YqV8G/

Also, I suggest you only have one Add button. You don't need to duplicate add buttons unless you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
      var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      var iteration = lastRow - 1;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
      var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var el = document.createElement('input');

      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'name_' + i;
      el.id = 'name_' + i;
      el.size = 20;
      el.maxlength = 20;
      firstCell.appendChild(el);

     // alert(i);
      i++;
      frm.h.value=i;
    //  alert(i);
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="addtablerow3.php" method="post" name="frm" id="frm"> 
<input type="button" value="Add New Item" onclick="addRow();" />
</form>

<table id="table1" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="10%" bgcolor="#336666">HI </td>
    <td> this </td><td>is </td><td> 4</td>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
$(".Add").click(function () {
            $(".tbl").append(newRow);
            ddlEditSelected = '0';
            numberOfRows++;

        });




        var newRow = "<tr><td><select class='status1' id='ddlStatus'  > <option value='0'>--Select--</option><option value='2'>Schedule Variance</option>" +
                           "<option value='3'>Effort Variance</option>" +
                           "<option value='4'>GOM Variance</option>" +
                            "<option value='5'>Defect Density per Person Day of Effort</option>" +
                             "<option value='6'>Resource Variance</option>" +
                              "<option value='7'>Process Quality</option>" +
                               "<option value='8'>Non Billable CRs</option>" +


                           "<td><input type='text' class='source1' id='txtSource' name='Source'  maxlength='3' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onblur='return checkvalidation(this)' ></td></td></tr>";
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" id="qualitygoal1" class="tbl">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th align="center">Parameter</th>
                    <th align="center">WeightAge</th>


                </tr>

                @foreach (var data in Model)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="spanStatus" id="lblStatus_@data.Id" destinationid="@data.Parameter">@data.ParameterValue</span>
                            <select class="status" id="ddlStatus_@data.Id">
                                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                                <option value="2">Schedule Variance</option>
                                <option value="3">Effort Variance</option>
                                <option value="4">GOM Variance</option>
                                <option value="5">Defect Density per Person Day of Effort</option>
                                <option value="6">Resource Variance</option>
                                <option value="7">Process Quality</option>
                                <option value="8">Non Billable CRs</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="spanSource" id="lblSource_@data.Id">@data.Weightages</span>
                            <input class="Source" id="txtSource_@data.Id" type="text" value="@data.Weightages" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onblur="return checkvalidation(this)" />
                        </td>



                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**add button** 



<div align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Add Phase" class="Add" />

        <input type="button" value="Save" class="saved" />
        <input type="button" value="Close" class="cancel" />



    </div>
```